# Convert list of AppleScript strings to a Swift array

Tags: swift, applescript, nsapplescript

I have a complicated AppleScript that returns a list of strings that I need to access from Swift. I've boiled it down to a simple example and I just can't figure out how to map the AppleScript strings to an array of Swift strings.

```
let listOfStringsScript = """
                          set listOfStrings to { "one", "two", "three" }
                          """

 if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: listOfStringsScript) {
    var errorDict: NSDictionary? = nil
    let resultDescriptor = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)

    if errorDict == nil {
      // TODO: convert the resultDescriptor (NSAppleEventDescriptor) into an array of strings
      print(resultDescriptor)
      // OUTPUT: <NSAppleEventDescriptor: [ 'utxt'("one"), 'utxt'("two"), 'utxt'("three") ]>
    }
}
```

Comment: Just iterate thru the NSAppleEventDescriptor and pull out the strings one by one and append them to an array?

Comment: @matt That is what I did (I updated the question). I didn't initially know you could iterate through the descriptor.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsappleeventdescriptor/1408027-atindex Just a matter of consulting the docs really :)

Comment: Is the script part of your app? (As opposed to user-supplied.) If so, you’ll find it a lot simpler to [call AppleScript directly from Swift](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge.

Answer (score 2):

Answer with help from @Alexander and @MartinR:

```
extension NSAppleEventDescriptor {

  func toStringArray() -> [String] {
    guard let listDescriptor = self.coerce(toDescriptorType: typeAEList) else {
      return []
    }

    return (0..<listDescriptor.numberOfItems)
      .compactMap { listDescriptor.atIndex($0 + 1)?.stringValue }
  }

}

...

let resultDescriptor = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&errorDict)
let subjectLines = resultDescriptor.toStringArray()
```

Comment: I would combine the 2 `if` statements inside the loop to just `if let s = listDescriptor.atIndex(i)?.stringValue {`.

Comment: Note that `1...listDescriptor.numberOfItems` crashes for an empty array. Suggestion: `(0..<listDescriptor.numberOfItems).compactMap { listDescriptor.atIndex($0+1)?.stringValue }`

Comment: @MartinR Good catch

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to gather the Apple Script result as lines of text separated by line breaks and then parse the string in Swift.

So break up the Apple Script result using

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
```

Then simply parse

```swift
let selectedItems = scriptExecuted.stringValue!
let selectedItemsFiltered = selectedItems.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

`.components` returns a string array